# How to export WebAssembly function?

Tags: javascript, async-await, webassembly

What I am trying to do is WASM loader with given requirements:

1. Immadiately import WASM function only once during runtime.
2. In other IIFE function immadiately call WASM function. Wait for it to load if not present.
3. Export it (testWASM) so it can be asynchronously called from other modules.

This works:

```
let testWASM;

  (async() => {
    const config = {
        env: {
            __memory_base: 0,
            __table_base: 0,
            memory: new WebAssembly.Memory({
                initial: 256,
            }),
            table: new WebAssembly.Table({
                initial: 0,
                element: 'anyfunc',
            }),
        }
      }
      const fetchPromise = fetch(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/hello.wasm');
      const {instance} = await WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetchPromise, config);
      testWASM = instance.exports.fib;
      console.log(testWASM());
  })();

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(testWASM());
}, 2000)
```

Obviously setTimeout is really bad approach.

EDIT: hello.c:

```
#include <emscripten.h>

EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
int fib() {
  return 42;
}
```

build command:

```
emcc hello.c -Os -s WASM=1 -s SIDE_MODULE=1 -o hello.wasm
```

EDIT:

This works great in terms of exporting but I think it doesn't meet first requirement. It's very slow and I think it's due to fetching each time function is called:

wasm.js

```js
module.exports = async () => {
  const config = {
    env: {
      __memory_base: 0,
      __table_base: 0,
      memory: new WebAssembly.Memory({
        initial: 256
      }),
      table: new WebAssembly.Table({
        initial: 0,
        element: "anyfunc"
      })
    }
  };
  const fetchPromise = fetch(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/hello.wasm");
  const { instance } = await WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(
    fetchPromise,
    config
  );
  return instance.exports.fib();
};
```

And then we can use this as follows:

```js
import * as foo from './wasm.js'

const bar = async () => {
  console.log(await foo())
}

bar(); //42
```

Comment: @BumsikKim updated my answer, I don't have text-wasm version anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work fine:

```js
let cache;

module.exports = async (x, y, z) => {
  if (cache) {
    return cache(x, y, z);
  } else {
    const config = {
      env: {
        __memory_base: 0,
        __table_base: 0,
        memory: new WebAssembly.Memory({
          initial: 256
        }),
        table: new WebAssembly.Table({
          initial: 0,
          element: "anyfunc"
        })
      }
    };
    const fetchPromise = fetch(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/hello.wasm");
    const { instance } = await WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(
      fetchPromise,
      config
    );
    cache = instance.exports.mandelIter;
    return instance.exports.mandelIter(x, y, z);
  }
};
```

But for some reason it's slower approx 0.1s than normal JS function. Weird...